# Converting object to CLOB

Tags: java, oracle

I have a object array( it is an output of a native query in Oracle database) out of which the first element is of CLOB data type which needs to converted to a java String object. How would I achieve this? Please help.

```
 String sql = "select id, data from mytable";
            List< Object[] > results = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();
Map< Long, String > map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Object[] result : results) {
            map.put(((Number) result[0]).longValue(), (String) result[1]);
        }
```

data is a column in mydata table with CLOB data type.
result(1) would have my CLOB data

While putting in the HashMap I need to parse the result(1) as String.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including the java (and, if necessary, SQL) code necessary to replicate your issue.

Comment: added my code. Please check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Retrive the CLOB value from Oracle using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486648/how-to-retrive-the-clob-value-from-oracle-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the CLOB is small enough ( <`Integer.MAX_VALUE`) you can do the following :

```
clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());
```

(Just have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169732/most-efficient-solution-for-reading-clob-to-string-and-string-to-clob-in-java))

**EDIT :**

The code you submitted in your question should become:

```
String sql = "select id, data from mytable";
List< Object[] > results = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();
Map< Long, String > map = new HashMap<>();
Clob clob = (Clob)result[1];
String value = clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());
map.put(((Number) result[0]).longValue(), value);
```

Please note that the loop in your original code was absolutely useless so I removed it.

Check also that `result[1]` is a `java.sql.Clob`

Comment: I have updated my query. Could you please check now?

Comment: @PeaceIsPearl Sorry but I don't see what more do you need except that you have to replace `clob` by `((Clob)result[1])]`. I can add this in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for editing the code. But I need the for loop as I am expecting multiple id and data rows. Never mind, that is not a problem. I tried the following thing
Clob data = (Clob) result[1];
The data looks like this :
clob2: STRINGDECODE('name ''pearl'' \n validations'). 
Searched further about STRINGDECODE function and it is there as I have a newline character in the clob data.If I remove the new line characters I see that data looks like this:
clob2: ('name ''pearl'' validations')
I am trying to make this query run on H2 database.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to my query, got rid of the native query and used hibernate instead.
Mapped my CLOB column with javax.persistence.Lob

```
 @Lob
 @Column(name = "DATA")
 byte[] clobData
```