# Creating a CLOB object from custom class object

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, clob

I have in my `Entity` class a field which is a `CLOB` type which represents a column in my `Oracle`. database. I want to write into this field a object from this class:

```
class Person{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Integer age;
    // getters, setters, constructors
}
```

Something like this:

```
Person personObject = new Person();
Clob myClob = saveAsClob(personObject);
// save it into Oracle DB
```

How to achieve something like this? Convert my object into `JSONObject` and then save it as `String`? Or maybe is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by archive, but if you want to archive it in a json file, it will be like that:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person obj = new Person();

//Object to JSON in file, you can change the link
mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\file.json"), obj);

//Object to JSON in String
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
```

Comment: My bad. I want something like this, here is this flow:
createPersonObj --> createClobObj --> (put into `OracleDB`) --> getClobObj --> getPersonObj.
When I said archive - I thought about `to achieve`. There was my typo, sorry.

Comment: in this case I think you have to pass by a table, you can create a function like that 

public void insertClobInDataBase(Person obj){
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(.....);
     String sql = "insert into table (attribut) values (?);
     PreparedStatment psmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
     psmt.setClob(1, obj.get...) //getter used in the class
     int rs =psmt.executeUpdate();
then you can call it everytime you have a new Clob type, but in your case I don't think so, for a person you can use the 3 attributs

Comment: Ok I know it, but I don't know how to convert a `Person` object into `Clob` object. Do you know maybe solution for that?

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44411710/converting-object-to-clob