# How to fetch full xml in clob data type in java from DB if it is containg more than 4000 charcter in xml file

Tags: java, xml, clob, domparser

I'm forming 1 xml and keeping into DB with clob type in oracleDB.

However, when I'm trying to retrieve it, then clob type in java returning only 4000 character and shows preFetchDataSize is 4000.

So if xml is big then it won't populate full xml so while parsing it will give SAXParserEXception?

Can any one tell how to populate all xml in a single shot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486648/how-to-retrive-the-clob-value-from-oracle-using-java and http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/ReadCLOBsdatafromdatabase.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Retrive the CLOB value from Oracle using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486648/how-to-retrive-the-clob-value-from-oracle-using-java)