# While accessing the CLOB data (approx size 1305 KB) from Oracle DB getting null value through JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jboss6.x, ojdbc

The code is deployed on  JBOSS server sitting on LINUX Environment. Below is code to access the CLOB data from oracle using JDBC API.

JDBC jar used is ojdbc6.jar.
JAVA version  : jdk1.8.0_221-amd64 
Oracle java verion : 1.8.0_121

```
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class GetGenericPDFData {

     public String GetPDFData(String SolutionID) throws IOException {

           String PDFData = null;

           try {

                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ServerIP:1521:SID","username","password");

                String Query = "select pdf_data from stage1.pdf_queue where system_id in (select system_id from (select * from pdf_queue where solution_id = ? 
and status = 'Completed' order by time_stamp desc) where rownum=1)";

                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(Query);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, SolutionID);

                ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); 

                while(rs.next()){

                     PDFData = rs.getString("pdf_data");

                }

                //Below data is coming out as null
                System.out.println(PDFData);

                con.close();

           } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block               
                System.out.println("GetGenericPDFData.GetPDFData 7");               
                e.printStackTrace();            
                PDFData = "false";              
           }

           return PDFData;
     }

}
```

Comment: And it works with smaller clobs?

Comment: Note that PDFs are binary not text, so blobs are probably a better idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Retrive the CLOB value from Oracle using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486648/how-to-retrive-the-clob-value-from-oracle-using-java)

Comment: Yes, it is working with smaller clobs. Previously it worked for larger clobs also, just one day back it is returning null value.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually getting null back, rather than no rows? You haven't shown any debugging to check it actually goes into the result set loop. And what happens if you run that query manually for that ID?

Comment: Yes I am sure that it is actually getting null value. If we run the query manually in sql developer the clob data is coming.

Comment: Also note that above code (EAR file) is deployed in JBOSS server then only the issue is occuring. But when the class file is executed in eclipse the clob data is coming.