# Getting the java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Clob

Tags: java, mysql

Getting the java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Clob Error when trying to convert String into Clob type . we are using Mysql database .java side we are using Hibernate NativeQuery .

```
Query nativeQuery= entityManager.createNativeQuery(QueryConstants.GetDbDetails);
        
        nativeQuery.unwrap(SQLQuery.class)
        .setParameterList("crisilTicker", crisilTickerList);
        
        
        List<Object[]> list=nativeQuery.getResultList();
        try{
            if(list !=null && !list.isEmpty()){
                for(Object[] obj :list){
                    java.sql.Clob clobevalue =(java.sql.Clob) obj[0];
                    String metaDataStr =clobevalue.getSubString(1, (int) clobevalue.length());
                    JSONObject metaDataJson =new JSONObject(metaDataStr);
                    JSONObject metaData = metaDataJson.getJSONObject("sheetMetadata");
                    Iterator<String> keys = metaData.keys();
                    while (keys.hasNext()) {
```

getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Clob error

Comment: I need Clob type instead of String

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to Retrive the CLOB value from Oracle using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486648/how-to-retrive-the-clob-value-from-oracle-using-java)

Comment: You cannot cast a String to a Clob. That is not how Java works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to cast to String instead of Clob type?

```
String metaDataStr = (String) obj[0];
```

And remove this line in your code

```
java.sql.Clob clobevalue =(java.sql.Clob) obj[0];
```

Comment: I need Clob instead of String

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cast String to Clob, use below :-

```
 java.sql.Clob clobevalue = new new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob(((String)obj[0]).toCharArray());
```

Comment: obj[0].toCharArray()  here toCharArray() getting error because of obj[0] doesn't have toCharArray()

Comment: Cast obj[0] to String. Edit made to the answer.